# Unable to show result or selected elements from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

im new to php and trying to connect my db to php and test some queries but i can't get the result to print or show

```
$database = "kamel";

$c = mysql_connect($hostname) or die("Connecting to MySQL failed");

mysql_select_db($database);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT* FROM captain");

$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $r

?>
```

Comment: There is no space between `SELECT` and `*`. Try `SELECT * FROM captain`

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`. The `mysql_*` API has a `mysql_error()` function which helps you to find out what the error is

Answer (score 0):

I see several Problems with your code:

1. use `var_dump($r);` or `print_r($r);` to print an array (btw. u missed a `;`)
2. use PDO or mysqli to connect to a mysql database. "mysql_" was removed in PHP 7 and deprecated since 5.5
   see: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php for more informations.
   The link gives you some simple examples too.

Answer (score 0):

where remaing data base connection
try the following connection

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```